# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Node Express Fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, fetch

I know that many people experienced very similar problems but fixes that worked for them didn't do anything for me. Whatever I do I get:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api/places/comments/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I am using node with express and here is my app.js file (part relevant to CORS):

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT"
  );
  next();
});
app.use("/api/places", placesRouter);
```

Then route file (relevent for route that is not working)

```
placesRouter.post("/comments/test", requireLogin, addComment);
```

And finally the handler:

```
  const addCommentHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/places/comments/test`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: { comment: formState.inputs.comment.value },
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log(responseData);
    } catch (e) {}
  };
```

I know for a fact that body is sent and I have also tried in in Postman and it works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens when you instead try using the npm cors package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors to CORS-enable the server?

Comment: @sideshowbarker

Same result, no changes at all

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed Check out this once it may be because of some browser extension

Answer (score -1):

You are doing `res.setHeader()` instead of `req.setHeader()` !

```
const app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  req.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  req.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT"
  );
  next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/api/places", placesRouter);
```

Comment: Changed res to req and it didn't help

Comment: You should move it to the first middleware, will edit my answer in 1 minute